# SQL Query Issue Sum

Tags: sql, zoho

I am using the sum query and using it to sum different columns from two tables, but it is returning double the value than expected. Why is that happening? Here's the query:

```sql
SELECT SUM("A")+ SUM ("A-1")
FROM "Testing101" ,"Testing102"
```

By the way, I am using the ZOHO Reports software to create these queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a cross join so you will count elements in each table multiple times.

Try using subselects instead:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM("A") FROM "Testing101") +
    (SELECT SUM("A-1") FROM "Testing102")
```

Comment: its returning this error:Parsing of SQL query failed. Please check the SQL syntax.
Some tips:
Encountered "(" at line 3, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
   <EOF> 
   "," ...
   "FROM" ...
   "GROUP" ...
   "HAVING" ...
   "INTO" ...
   "+" ...
   "WHERE" ...
   "BULK" ...
   "AT ISOLATION" ...
   "START" ...
   "CONNECT" ...
   "OPTION" ...
   "FETCH" ...
   "GO" ...
   "COMPUTE" ...
   "ORDER" ...
   "FOR" ...
   "WITH" ...
   "LIMIT" ...
   "OFFSET" ...
   "INTERSECT" ...
   "UNION" ...
   "MINUS" ...
   "EXCEPT" ...

Comment: ok cool, now i have to sum "sum_101" and "sum-102" in the same query, ...see what i am looking to do is to create a combined sum of A  and A-1

Comment: @EinsjamNeutron: To find the total sum you can use the addition operator to add together the two values.

Comment: Can u please post the whole query please  :) sorry to take much time